# Under which conditions $-(-c)^{-n}c^n=(-1)^{1-n}$?

Tags: calculus, exponentiation

Set $c>0$ and define $0\leq n \leq m$ and integer.

Do we need certain conditions to be satisfied so we have
$$-(-c)^{-n}c^n=(-1)^{1-n}?$$

When we try to simplify the LHS in *Mathematica*, we don't get the expression on the RHS.

Comment: What expression do you get?

Comment: @abiessu It returns the same expression!

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+-%28-x%29%5E%28-n%29*x%5En) appears to have no difficulty.

Comment: It's hard to help you if you don't share what exactly you typed in Mathematica. Also, why you talk about $m$ and then don't  use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where you're using $m$ but I conclude
$$-(-c)^{-n}c^n = -\frac{1}{(-c)^n}c^n = -\big(\frac{c}{-c}\big)^n = -(-1)^n = (-1)^{1-n}.$$

This shouldn't need more conditions than $c \neq 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think $c \neq 0$ suffices.

Comment: Thanks you're right. I corrected it in my answer.

Comment: @Eric Does this mean $(-c)^{-n}c^k=(-1)^{-n}c^{-n}c^k=(-1)^{-n}c^{k-n}$ for $k\geq 1$ and integer?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: Maple is the same.  It does not simplify $-(-c)^{-n} c^n$.  But if you tell Maple that $c \ne 0$ and $n$ is an integer, then Maple does simplify it.

Answer (score -1):

Given $c$ a positive number and integer $n$, we have

$$-(-c)^{-n}c^n\underset{a^{-n}=\frac 1{a^n}}=-\frac {c^n}{(-c)^n}\underset{\frac{a^n}{b^n}=(\frac ab)^n}=-\left(\frac c{-c}\right)^n\underset{\frac a{-a}=-1}=-(-1)^n\underset{a\cdot a^n=a^{n+1}}=(-1)^{n+1}$$

Note that $(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)^{1-n}(-1)^{2n}=(-1)^{1-n}((-1)^2)^n=(-1)^{1-n}1^n=(-1)^{1-n}$.

Troubleshooting mathematica results is a question for the stack exchange dedicated to that platform, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions.

Comment: So from your answer and the answer of @Eric, $(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)^{1-n}$?

Comment: That's correct.  Consider the exponents modulo $2$...

Comment: Thank you. I'm confused. Could you please elaborate your comment?

Comment: Since $(-1)^2=1$ we can multiply or divide by this amount as many times as we want.  Adding $n+1$ to $1-n$ gives $2$, so we would get $(-1)^2=1$ showing the expressions are equal.

Comment: I have expounded on the previous posting...